# Filtering data in UL list based on content of Input box - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an input box in which user will enter text. Based on this text my UL list items should get filtered. For eg, on "**Ab**" in text box - Only **Abbas** and **Abid** must show in the <li> tags of the UL list.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angularScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<input type="text" />
<ul><li ng-repeat="x in people">{{x.name}}</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

angularScript.js

```
//1. appDeclaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//2. controllers
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Peter";
    $scope.people = [{"name":"Abbas"},{"name":"Tina"},{"name":"Abid"}];
});
```

Can someone help me out with some filter based on text in input so that only those lis are populated which match with the texts in input box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you'll need an ng-model in your `<input>` element.

`<input ng-model="filter" type="text" />`

And then your ng-repeat would look like:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in people | filter:filter">{{x.name}}</li>
```

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Yep, but when nothing is written in input box .... none of the li appears ;( ... In this case all li's must appear!

Comment: In your controller set an initial value for $scope.filter ex. $scope.filter = $scope.people[0] and it will always get populated with first person in a list after a controller is initialized

Comment: Thanx buddy ... It did ;)

Comment: As far as i know assigning $scope.filter to '' (empty string) should get every item in your list and keep that input field 'empty'.

Comment: Yep, it did. I made some mistake ... ;-/